# Notification out of screen

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, notifications

The notifications extrude the screen. I am on Ubuntu 11.10 with Gnome3.2.

[image: notifications extrude the screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [patched version of notify-osd](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/configurable-notifyosd-notifications.html) that you can use to customize all aspects of the notification bubbles, including position on the screen.

Other possible tweaks include:

- change font and background colors, opacity, size, corner radius
- change the timeout (only works if an application specifies the timeout)
- disable fade out
- close the notifications on click

You can install the application after enabling the ppa, as [described here](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/configurable-notifyosd-bubbles-for.html).

Answer (score 0):

The issues lies on the current *monitor resolution* of ubuntu that doesn't your monitor. So, change the monitor resolution that suite for your desktop. Then the notification diplayed within your desktop

Comment: I don't think this is the correct answer: On the screenshot, you can clearly see that the position of the username button thing is correct, as are the rounded borders of the upper bar.